# camel / spring-redis not writing to remote host

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have the following code

```
 private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // from("spring-redis://localhost:6379?command=GET&serializer=#serializer")
            from("spring-redis://10.0.0.247:6379?command=GET&serializer=#serializer")
            .setHeader("CamelRedis.Key", constant("testKEY"))
            .to("stream:out")
          .beanRef("foo");
        }
    }
```

I am quite puzzeled. It works well and inserts the right Key/Value pair when I run redis on the local host, however, when I want to do the same on a remote host (here: 10.0.0.247) a tcpdump shows that it does not even try to contact the remote host via the network!

How can I fix this? I have tried manually with r`edis-client -h 10.0.0.247` and it worked. I have also tried via name-resolution something like spring-redis://rd.my:6379?... but still now joy.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you put the jedis jar in you class path? 

 <dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: Yes, on localhost it all works. I read something that it cannot route to instances outside the same JVM? Would this mean here that it can only work on localhost?

Comment: No, that is not true. I ran some integration test by using the ip address (not the localhost), the test passed without any error.  Can you check the log of the redis client?

Comment: Thanks. Got a bit further. The issue seems to be that stream:out is not working as I envisioned. Would you know where to find a working example?

Comment: You can use log component instead of the stream component, if you just want to write something out :)

Comment: with log: I can write to a remote host?

Comment: No, you can try camel-jms component, if you want to send the message to an other remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port 6379 is allowed or opened for remote connections  by

> telnet 10.0.0.247 6379